# how can I confine terminal in a directory as in chroot?

Tags: gnome-terminal, chroot

I want to set a particular directory as top directory temporarily. Let's say I open terminal in `/home/me/mychroot` how can I set **mychroot** directory as top directory for that terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest solution to my question is [proot](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/proot.1.html) but it doesn't work as intended. For example when I run it like

```
proot -w  ~/mychroot
```

and when I change  to parent directory

```
cd ..
```

and run

```
ls
```

it really changes  to parent directory, it must have confined in `~/mychroot` directory

Anyway I found a script in one of the forums and modified it to my needs. In original script it doesn't work with `/usr/sbin/chroot` I replaced it with `fakechroot fakeroot chroot` and added a few new lines.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 <enter_name_of_your_chroot_directory>"
else
  #remove trail slash
  DESTINATION_PATH=$PWD/${1%/}
  mkdir -p $DESTINATION_PATH
  if [ ! -d "$DESTINATION_PATH" ]; then
    echo "Invalid destination path ${DESTINATION_PATH} it does not exists"
    exit
  fi
  
  if [ ! -d "${DESTINATION_PATH}/dev" ]; then
    echo "Create dir path ${DESTINATION_PATH}/dev"
    mkdir -p ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"dev
  fi
  
  if ! grep -qs ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"dev /proc/mounts; then
    mount --bind /dev ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"dev
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "Mount success ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"dev"
    else
      echo "Something went wrong with the mount ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"dev"
    fi
  fi
  
  if [ ! -d "${DESTINATION_PATH}/proc" ]; then
    echo "Create dir path ${DESTINATION_PATH}/proc"
    mkdir -p ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"proc
  fi
  
  if ! grep -qs ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"proc /proc/mounts; then
    mount --bind /proc ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"proc
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "Mount success ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"proc"
    else
      echo "Something went wrong with the mount ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"proc"
    fi
  fi
  
  if [ ! -d "${DESTINATION_PATH}/sys" ]; then
    echo "Create dir path ${DESTINATION_PATH}/sys"
    mkdir -p ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"sys
  fi
  
  if ! grep -qs ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"sys /proc/mounts; then
    mount --bind /sys ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"sys
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "Mount success ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"sys"
    else
      echo "Something went wrong with the mount ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"sys"
    fi
  fi
  
  if [ ! -d "${DESTINATION_PATH}/dev/pts" ]; then
    echo "Create dir path ${DESTINATION_PATH}/dev/pts"
    mkdir -p ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"dev/pts
  fi
  
  if ! grep -qs ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"dev/pts /proc/mounts; then
    mount --bind /dev/pts ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"dev/pts
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "Mount success ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"dev/pts"
    else
      echo "Something went wrong with the mount ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"dev/pts"
    fi
  fi
  
  if [ ! -d "${DESTINATION_PATH}/etc" ]; then
    echo "Create dir path ${DESTINATION_PATH}/etc"
    mkdir -p ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"etc
    cp /etc/resolv.conf ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"etc/resolv.conf
  fi
  
  for i in $( ldd /bin/bash | grep -v dynamic | cut -d " " -f 3 | sed 's/://' | sort | uniq )
  do
    cp --parents $i ${DESTINATION_PATH}
  done
  
  # ARCH amd64
  if [ -f /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ]; then
    cp --parents /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /${DESTINATION_PATH}
  fi
  
  # ARCH i386
  if [ -f  /lib/ld-linux.so.2 ]; then
    cp --parents /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /${DESTINATION_PATH}
  fi
  
  echo "Chroot jail is ready: ${DESTINATION_PATH}"
  
  if [ ! -d "${DESTINATION_PATH}/bin" ]; then
    echo "Create dir path ${DESTINATION_PATH}/bin"
    mkdir -p ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/"bin
    cp /bin/{cat,echo,rm,bash,sh,ls,mkdir} ${DESTINATION_PATH}"/bin/"
  fi
  
  fakechroot fakeroot chroot ${DESTINATION_PATH}
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

To change your working directory, try using the following command

`gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/dir`

You can check whether the changes have taken plac using the `pwd` command.

Alternatively, open "~/.bashrc", scroll to the bottom and add a change directory command -

`cd ~/mychroot`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work. When I set it like `gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/me/mychroot` it opens another window in `/home/me`

Comment: it doesn't set mychroot as root directory, it sets working directory. I need something like chroot does